# TeamCity extra sync from Perforce

Tags: teamcity, perforce

I have problem with Extra sync option on TeamCity.

On page **Edit VCS Root** I am specifying `Label/changelist to sync:` with change list number for example `900001` and in field 'Extra sync options:' also added some changes that I want to apply `900002`.

In log I see message

```
[Updating sources for root 'Current1.02', revision/label: @900001] Running 'p4 sync -f //depot/.../.../.../MainView.cpp@900002' in directory C:\BuildFolder\Desktop
```

In result i have `.exe` without any signs of changes that was submitted in 900002.

Why it does not apply those change? Where can be problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, but if it's running this command:

`p4 sync -f //depot/.../.../.../MainView.cpp@900002`

it might be hitting problems with too many embedded wildcards.